# Add class not working after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery

add class works before ajax call but not after ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../ajax/basket.php",
            data: {planproductId: productIDVal, action: "addToBasket"},
            success: function(theResponse) {
                if (theResponse.indexOf("<li>" < 0))
                {
                    $("#notication").addClass('error-box');
                    $("#notification").text(theResponse);
                    $("#notificationsLoader").empty();
                    return;
                }
            }
       });
```

```
.error-box {
    background:#ffecec url('../img/error.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #f5aca6;
}
```

Comment: Install spell check to show that `notication` is spelled wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition is wrong - it should be like this (*assuming `#notication` being a typo*)

```
 if (theResponse.indexOf("<li>") < 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be...

```
$("#notification").addClass('error-box');
```

Not...

```
$("#notication").addClass('error-box');
```

And this should be...

```
 if (theResponse.indexOf("<li>") < 0)
```

Comment: I wouldn't assume that `notication` is an error. The OP wouldn't need to re-select the same element.

Comment: Yeah he wouldn't need to, but people do....all the time.